# Gradle script : How to create and write data in XML file

Tags: android, xml, gradle, groovy, build.gradle

I am creating xml and via using gradle script and writing some data in xml file. I have created .gradle file and after running the gradle file i am not able to achieve the exact format for the xml file. i am posting my code below: Please anyone guide me .
import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder

```
task generatepublicxml {

    //def resDir = project.projectDir.absolutePath + "/src/main/res-public"

    // Create new public.xml with writer
    new File("/home/signity/Desktop/public.xml").withWriter { writer ->
        // Create MarkupBuilder with 4 space indent
        def destXml = new MarkupBuilder(new IndentPrinter(writer, "    ", true));
        def destXmlMkp = destXml.getMkp();

        // GIST NOTE: our project needed the ResourceName suppression, but its not needed in general
        destXml.resources('xmlns:tools': 'http://schemas.android.com/tools', 'tools:ignore': 'ResourceName')
                {
            // Leave file comment
            destXmlMkp.yield "\r\n"
            destXmlMkp.comment("AUTO-GENERATED FILE.  DO NOT MODIFY. public.xml is generated by the generatepublicxml gradle task")

        }
    }
}
```

My Required File format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="remoteAccessConsumerKey">3MVG92mNMNiWvonjPDM9qqaDip0MFl9TGc</string>
    <string name="oauthRedirectURI">saleschap:///mobilesdk/detect/oauth/done</string>

    <string-array name="oauthScopes">
        <item>api</item>
        <item>web</item>
        <item>refresh_token</item>
    </string-array>

    <string name="androidPushNotificationClientId"></string>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since I see you are doing this from within a gradle build file, first a note on gradle execution phases.

I would assume that you want your code to be run when the task executes and not when the build file is loaded. If so, you need to put the code within a `doFirst` or `doLast` block within the task. If you write your code as in your question, the code will be executed when the build file is loaded, whether or not the task `generatepublicxml` is run or not (i.e. you could run some totally different task and the code will still be run).

This is often not obvious when starting out with gradle and I would recommend reading the [gradle docs on the build lifecycle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html) if this feels confusing.

With that out of the way, the following build.gradle:

```groovy
import groovy.xml.*

task generatepublicxml {
  doLast { 
    file("public.xml").withWriter { writer ->
      // Create MarkupBuilder with 4 space indent
      def xml = new MarkupBuilder(new IndentPrinter(writer, "    ", true))

      xml.doubleQuotes = true
      xml.mkp.xmlDeclaration(version: '1.0', encoding: 'utf-8')

      xml.resources('xmlns:tools': 'http://schemas.android.com/tools', 'tools:ignore': 'ResourceName') {
        string(name: 'remoteAccessConsumerKey', '3MVG92mNMNiWvonjPDM9qqaDip0MFl9TGc')
        string(name: 'oauthRedirectURI',        'saleschap:///mobilesdk/detect/oauth/done')
        'string-array'(name: 'oauthScopes') {
          item('api')
          item('web')
          item('refresh_token')
        }
        string(name: 'androidPushNotificationClientId')

        // Leave file comment
        mkp.yield('\n    ')
        mkp.comment("AUTO-GENERATED FILE.  DO NOT MODIFY. public.xml is generated by the generatepublicxml gradle task")

      }
    }
  }
}
```

when run:

```
~> gradle generatepublicxml

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 0s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

results in the following `public.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:ignore="ResourceName">
    <string name="remoteAccessConsumerKey">3MVG92mNMNiWvonjPDM9qqaDip0MFl9TGc</string>
    <string name="oauthRedirectURI">saleschap:///mobilesdk/detect/oauth/done</string>
    <string-array name="oauthScopes">
        <item>api</item>
        <item>web</item>
        <item>refresh_token</item>
    </string-array>
    <string name="androidPushNotificationClientId" />
    <!-- AUTO-GENERATED FILE.  DO NOT MODIFY. public.xml is generated by the generatepublicxml gradle task -->
</resources>
```

If you don't want the `xmlns` attribute etc on the `resources` element you can just do:

```xml
xml.resources {
...
}
```

which results in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   ...
```